# Grammar of "Frye’s postulates are blessedly of this world"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Excerpted from [thesmartset.com](http://thesmartset.com/anatomy-of-wonder/)

> Unlike theology, however, Frye’s postulates are **blessedly** of this world.

Blessedly is an adverb, but I don't see any verb or adjective that it describes, it seems more appropriate to use ***blessed***, an adjective.

So what's the deal here?

Comment: **of this world** is the **adjectival phrase** used to describe **postulates** (following **are**), **blessedly** is the adverb describing **of this world** and is also a pun on **theology**

Comment: The verb is humbly there, *are*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of certain adverbs as serving a deictic purpose, expressing the speaker's attitude with respect to the truth asserted in the predication.

> The blizzard *thankfully* has passed us by.

That could be paraphrased "I am happy to say the blizzard has passed us by" or "I am thankful that the blizzard has passed us by".